# Meteor basic HTTP authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Need to connect to an [external api: Vogogo](http://docs.vogogo.com/payment_api/v3#authentication).The hard part is converting the curl example into a valid Meteor HTTP.get call. Now here is the code I came up with

```
apiversionVogogo = 'v3';

Vogogo.listAllCustomers = function() {
    HTTP.get('https://api.vogogo.com/' + apiversionVogogo + '/customers', {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': {
                    user: clientID,
                    clientsecret: apisecret
                }
            }
        },
        function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    return;
}
```

The response is an error message:

```
error_message: 'HTTP Authorization expected"'
```

Can someone help me rewrite this basic HTTP authentication into a default format? In the docs an example is given with CURL.

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.vogogo.com/v3/customers' \
 --user clientsecret: \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Comment: Did you try setting the `auth` paramater in the options field instead of actually setting the `Authorization` in the headers? From Docs : `auth String
HTTP basic authentication string of the form "username:password"`

Comment: so that your request would look like  `HTTP.get('https://api.vogogo.com/' + apiversionVogogo + '/customers', { auth : "clientID:apisecret"})`

Comment: Thanks Nate! That worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `auth` parameter in the options field instead of actually setting the Authorization in the headers. From  the Docs : `auth String HTTP basic authentication string of the form "username:password"`. You're request would look like:

```
HTTP.get('https://api.vogogo.com/' + apiversionVogogo + '/customers', { auth : "clientID:apisecret"})
```